# How to iterate through an array of numbers in shell-script?

Tags: shell-script, array

I am trying to iterate through an array created after some command execution.
The code used is:

```
#!/bin/bash
mailx -H|grep '^ [UN]'>ListOfMessages.txt
msgNumbers=`cut -c 4-5 ListOfMessages.txt`
echo $msgNumbers
for msg in "${msgNumbers[@]}";
do
echo $msg;
echo $msg|mailx;
done
```

The ListOfMessages.txt look like:

```
 U  5 Sender1    Thu Aug 23 14:28  179/10454 Incident
 U  7 Sender2    Thu Aug 23 15:20  179/10456 Incident
 U  8 Sender3    Thu Aug 23 15:41  192/10801 Incident
 N  9 Sender4    Thu Aug 23 15:45  197/11011 Incident
```

The array is getting updated with the numbers 5 7 8 9 as required.
I keep getting "Bad Substitution" error(at the line where for loop starts).

Please advise me on the she-bang to be used.

Comment: It seems to be a follow-up on [How can we store the output of a command as an array in Unix shell script?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/463825).

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can see, you have no array in your code.  The variable `msgNumbers` is a string that holds the output of your `cut` command.

To iterate over the output of `cut`, use

```
#!/bin/bash

mailx -H | grep '^ [UN]' | cut -c 4-5 |
while read msg; do
    print 'msg = %s\s' "$msg"
done
```

This sends the output of `cut` into the `while` loop immediately following it, through the pipe (`|`).  The `while` loop will iterate with `msg` set to each individual line of output from `cut`.

The `cut` gets its data directly from the `grep` command, which removes the need for storing the data in an intermediate file or variable.

I removed the `echo $msg|mailx;` command because it did not make much sense to me (the `mailx` utility needs an address to send the data to).

The `grep`+`cut` could also be replaced by a single call to `awk` where we let `awk` do the work of both tools and output the second whitespace-delimited column when the regular expression matches:

```
#!/bin/bash

mailx -H | awk '/^ [UN]/ { print $2 }' |
while read msg; do
    print 'msg = %s\s' "$msg"
done
```

I'm not commenting further on the use of `mailx` as it is a non-standard utility which is implemented slightly differently across Unix systems (my version does not have a `-H` option, for example).

---

The `#!`-line looks ok to me, if you want the script to be executed by `bash` and if the `bash` executable is located at that path (which it commonly is on Linux systems, for example, but check with `command -v bash` on your system to be sure).  The code I have posted above is compatible with `/bin/sh`, so `bash` isn't *really* needed to run it (it would run in any `sh`-like shell).

Just make sure that the script is executable and that you run it without specifying an explicit interpreter.

Comment: The OP's probably on Solaris (10 or older) as they get Bourne shell error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Don't double quote the msgNumbers reference, and, msgNumbers is not an array, so the indexing is pointless.

Comment: okay...then can you advise me how to store the result of command: cut -c 4-5 ListOfMessages.txt  so that I can use the values one by one in a loop?

Comment: The first half tells how to make the for loop work, and the second half hints on improvement. Had the requestor given the input sample from the beginning, a more detailed answer (or even full blown solution) could have benn provided.

Answer (score 0):

Use `()` to store the value as an array.

```
msgNumbers=(`cut -c 4-5 ListOfMessages.txt`)
echo "${msgNumbers[@]}"
for msg in "${msgNumbers[@]}";
do
echo $msg;
done
```

Comment: Tried with your answer....But getting an error: Shell_script.sh: syntax error at line 4: `msgNumbers=' unexpected

Comment: @Devjith, again, you've tried to interpret the script with `sh`, not `bash`. Don't run the script as `sh the-script`. Do a `chmod a+x the-script` and then `./the-script`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is solved.
The problem was that msgNumbers was not an indexed array. So I changed the `for msg in "${msgNumbers[@]}";`to `for msg in ${msgNumbers};`.Now its working. The rest of the code is same as in my question.

Comment: It's still not an array, and now you rely on the shell doing word splitting of the string in your variable, and filename generation ("globbing") on the words generated by the word splitting. Your code would now break if the `IFS` variable is set to one or several digits.